# JSF Backing Bean (EJB) not called from JSF (using glassfish)

Tags: jsf, jpa, ejb, glassfish-3

I'm trying to create a questionnaire website using GlassFish, JSF/Primefaces and for database, I'm using the embedded derby DB of Glassfish. 
I followed this video tutorial (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aBjlR9HoR50) which is really good but I haven't managed to get my project to work properly. 
My project deploys successfully on Glassfish but when I see the webpage on the browser, it is obvious that the backing bean is not called from the xhtml page.

Here is the backing bean code:

```
package ac.hw.questionnaire;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.metamodel.EntityType;
import javax.persistence.metamodel.Metamodel;




import ac.hw.questionnaire.model.Question;

/**
 * Session Bean implementation class QuestionsEJB
 */
@Stateless
@LocalBean
@Named
public class QuestionsEJB {

    private Logger logging = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

    @PersistenceContext (unitName="QuestionnaireEmbeddedDB") 
    EntityManager em;

    private List<Question> questions;

    private String name;
    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */


    private EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        if (em==null){
            logging.info("EntityManager is null!");
            EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("QuestionnaireEmbeddedDB");
            em = emf.createEntityManager(); 
            if (em==null){
                logging.info("EntityManager is STILL null!");
            }
        }
            return em;


    } 
    public QuestionsEJB() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        logging.info("Logger: Constructor of QuestionsEJB called");
        if (getEntityManager()==null){
            return;
        }
        List resultList = em.createQuery("select q from Question q").getResultList();
        if (resultList==null){
            logging.info("ResultList is null");
        }else{
        logging.info("Constructor/Retrieved "+resultList.size()+" questions");
        }
    }

    public List<Question> getQuestions() {
        System.out.println("getQuestions method called");

        if (questions==null){
            this.questions = em.createQuery("select q from questions q").getResultList();
            System.out.println("Retrieved "+questions.size()+" questions");
        }
        return questions;
    }

    public String getMyText(){
        return "myTextFromEJB";
    }

    public void setQuestions(List<Question> questions) {
        this.questions = questions;
    }
    public String getName() {
        this.logging.info("Get name!");
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.logging.info("Set name!");
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Here is my xhtml page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<ui:composition template="WEB-INF/template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="content">

            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
                <h:outputLabel for="myText" value="MyText is:"></h:outputLabel>
                <h:outputText id="myText" value="#{QuestionsEJB.myText}">
                </h:outputText>
            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:panelGrid columns="4" cellpadding="5">
                <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Name:" style="font-weight:bold" />

                <p:inputText id="name" value="#{QuestionsEJB.name}" />

                <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="display" />

                <h:outputText value="#{QuestionsEJB.name}" id="display" />
            </h:panelGrid>
            <br />
            <p:dataTable var="qVar" value="#{QuestionsEJB.questions}">
                <h:column>#{qVar.questionText}</h:column>
            </p:dataTable>

    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
</html>
```

When I visit the xhtml page on the browser, none of the  values are displayed and the Submit button doesn't do anything which tells me that the facelet doesn't bind to the EJB.

My web.xml (inside WebContent/WEB-INF/) has the following content:

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" >
  <display-name>Questionnaire</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My beans.xml file (also inside WebContent/WEB-INF) is empty (nothing at all). 
My glassfish-web.xml file (also inside WebContent/WEB-INF) has the following content:

```
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app>
    <context-root>/QuestionnaireEmbeddedDB</context-root>
    <parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8"/>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

I have no exceptions on the server.log and the only unorthodox thing is that the EntityManager is null until I explicitly call the getEntityManager() method on the QuestionEJB.

Why can't I get the xhtml to connect to the backing bean?

Also, the template.xhtml has the following content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
    <title><ui:insert name="title">Questionnaire</ui:insert></title>
</h:head>

<body>
    <ui:debug hotkey="x"
        rendered="#{initParam['javax.faces.FACELETS_DEVELOPMENT']}" />

    <div id="header">
        <ui:insert name="header">
            <h1>Welcome to the privacy questionnaire... (header section)</h1>
            <!--  include your header file or uncomment the include below and create header.xhtml in this directory -->
            <!-- <ui:include src="header.xhtml"/> -->
        </ui:insert>
    </div>

    <h:body>
        <h:form id="mainForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div id="content">
                <ui:insert name="content">
        Content area.  See comments below this line in the source.
        <!--  include your content file or uncomment the include below and create content.xhtml in this directory -->
                    <!-- <div> -->
                    <!-- <ui:include src="content.xhtml"/> -->
                    <!-- </div> -->
                </ui:insert>
            </div>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
    <div id="footer">
        <ui:insert name="footer">
            <br />
            <br />Powered by Glassfish &amp; Eclipse. 
        <br /> 
        <!--  include your header file or uncomment the include below and create footer.xhtml in this directory -->
            <!--<ui:include src="footer.xhtml"/>  -->
        </ui:insert>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: jsf backing bean must have javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean annotation unless you configure beans with faces-config.xml. AFAIK there is no way to inject EJB directly to faces servlet. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/girch.html and http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_managed_beans.htm

Comment: Thank you! That moved things along. I am still wondering how the guy on the video got his to work without the @ManagedBean annotation or the faces-config file

Comment: Um, the default `@Named` injects your bean with a lowercase first letter into the view: `#{questionsEJB.name}` and so on. No need to use `@ManagedBean` when you're already using CDI (via `@Named`). And I don't get why you're using `@Stateless` on a bean used in a view?

Comment: Thank you for that also. It looks like it also works with the lowercase first letter and without the @ManagedBean. This is the first time I used EJBs. In the past, I've only used managed beans and had all the business logic in the managed bean. As mentioned before, I used that video tutorial to guide me and it suggested that the EJB be directly used from the view (as Stateless) and the narrator explicitly said that there is no reason to use ManagedBeans. I'm still trying to understand the difference between Stateless and Stateful though.